# Selenium 3: Cannot disable first run webpage

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am running some automated tasks with Selenium 3 (Java framework) and Firefox 48. Every now and then, however, the first run webpage will be called by Firefox when it starts. This interferes with the automation. I have tried to deactivate this behavior by using

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoPath);

FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();

fp.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
fp.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional",  "about:blank");

driver = new FirefoxDriver(fp);
```

I found this solution through a websearch but it seems this does not work in Selenium 3.

Is there any other way to prohibit the first run page from showing up? Alternatively a link to Selenium 2 binaries would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue on Chrome due to an extension. What I did is, after you initiate the driver, I opened a second tab when executing the driver and load the URL on that new one and then I closed the first tab.

You can open a new tab with the link like this:

```
String newTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("yourLink")).sendKeys(newTab);
```

After the new tab is opened, close the first tab and switch to the current working tab like this.

```
//Getting all tabs opened on the browser
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowsHandles());

//This will switch to the Firefox welcome tab and close it
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
driver.close();

//Move back to your website
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

If you have racing conditions issues, you can also do some implicit wait between switching tabs. Hope it works!

Comment: I had the same idea previously. Unfortunately, Opening a tab is also not working in Selenium 3. I think it was a bad move to publish a beta version of Selenium 3 and removing the binaries for Selenium 2. So I cannot even downgrade.

Comment: I see, for work and personal testing I use 2.53 Selenium Version, you can try to see if you can find it somewhere, keep in mind that for this version you need to use Firefox 44.0.2.